# Convergence proof that involves integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For $n\in N $ let

$a_n = \displaystyle \int_1^n \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx$.

Prove, for $m \geq n \geq 1$, that $|a_m - a_n| \leq n^{-1}$ and deduce that $(a_n)$ converges.

By integration by parts, or otherwise, demonstrate the existence of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_1^n \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$.

---

I simplified $|a_m - a_n|$ into $\displaystyle \int_{n}^m \frac{\cos x}{x^2} dx$.

Now I'm stuck on how to make this less than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $m\geq n\geq 1$,
$$
|a_n - a_m| = \left | \int_n^m \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2} \right | \leq \int_n^m \frac{1}{x^2}dx
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} \leq \frac{1}{n}
$$
Since $1/n \to 0$, this last term can be made as small as you want.

As for your second question, just use integration by parts, by taking $u = \frac{1}{x^2}$, and $dv = \cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

For the existence of the second limit, let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and $dv=\sin x\,dx$. Then $du=-\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ and we can take $v=-\cos x$. Thus
$$\int_1^n \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\left. -\frac{\cos x}{x}\right|_1^n -\int_1^n \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx.$$

Now let $n\to\infty$. The rest is taken care of by the fact that $\frac{\cos n}{n}\to 0$ and the first part of the question.